# How to avoid "Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length" and "Error in model.frame.default variable lengths differ" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a paired t test in R. The variables are of different length (ie data points), why is this causing an error when different lengths do not break an assumption of t tests?

Here is my code:

```
t.test(data$var, data$var, alternative="two.sided", var.eq=FALSE, paired=TRUE)
```

Comment: How do you expect to do a **paired** t-test with 2 vectors of different length? What happens to the data points without a pair?

Comment: ``??t.test: If ‘paired’ is ‘TRUE’ then both ‘x’ and ‘y’ must be specified and
     they must be the same length``

Comment: From the docs for t.test... If paired is TRUE then both x and y must be specified and *they must be the same length.*

Comment: Without the pair it I do not get the error. The data is the same unit measured under 2 states. However the amount of measurements per state was different that's why the lengths are different. Would a paired t test not be correct in this instance?

Comment: Regardless of how you designed the experiment, the two vectors still must be the same length for a paired t-test. Perhaps you could average them such that each unit has one summary measure per state.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for the feedback.

Comment: @Alex a paired t-test needs to have all pairs of datapoints. Try setting ``paired=F``

Comment: It seems like the *programming* portion of this question has been addressed. If you want to continue with the discussion and/or receive an answer ***why*** your assumptions on paired t-tests are a little off, then I suggest we migrate this to [stats.se], where a more pedagogic tone can be achieved (and this question will then be on-topic there). Alex, let me know (ping me) if that's what you want, I'll start the migration vote.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I think I am alright for now!